# Flutter box shadow

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am trying to develop shadow property for an inkwell with child of svg image.

This is what I trying to get done:[image],

And, this is what I am getting:[image]

Can I get help with this? Here is my code:

```
new InkWell(
                  onTap: _googleSignIn,
                  child: Container(
                    height: 60,
                    width: 60,
                    decoration: BoxDecoration(
                        color: Hexcolor('#e9f1fe'),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                        boxShadow: [
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Hexcolor('#C5D6F2'),
                              offset: Offset(6.0, 6.0),
                              blurRadius: 8.0,
                              spreadRadius: 1.0),
                          BoxShadow(
                              color: Colors.white,
                              offset: Offset(-4.0, -4.0),
                              blurRadius: 15.0,
                              spreadRadius: 1.0),
                        ]),
                    child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/icon/google.svg',fit: BoxFit.fill,),
                  )),
```

Answer (score 0):

Try change offset

```
offset: Offset(0.0, 0.0),
```